# Which is the right way to pass nested parameters to a build method ? (Ruby on Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I am building a very simple application managing users and keys. Keys are nested attributes of a user. I am inspired by [RailsCast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).
The models are defined as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  #Validations
  ---  
  #Relations
  has_many :keys, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keys, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Key < ApplicationRecord
  #Validations
  ---
  #Relations
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The users controller includes strong parameters:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:nom, :prenom, :section, :email, :password, keys_attributes: [:id, :secteur, :clef])
end
```

And I wish to initialize 1 key for each new user (users controller):

```
# GET /users/new
def new
  @user = User.new
  key = @user.keys.build({secteur: "Tous", clef: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678"})
end
```

I tried many ways to initialize the user's key, but I can't figure out how to pass parameters to it. User is always created, but the first key is not. No error message is issued.

Comment: you can just do key = @user.keys.build and then in the nested form add a hidden field with the value of a method that generates random keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the '{' tags inside the build method parameters. Should be:

```
key = @user.keys.new(secteur: "Tous", clef: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678")
```

Also, the build method is just an alias for 'new' and used to behave differently on rails 3 apps so I've always strayed away from it and just use the more familiar 'new' method.  Obviously don't forget to then save the object at some point in your controller.

Comment: Isn't the save method implicitly called for the nested attributes when saving the parent ?